# relative path with slash gulp src

Tags: gulp

here is my structure

```
_backroom
    _web
        _css
            app.css
    _lib
        gulpfile.js
```

In order to declare my source files for gulp config,
I would like to sepcify the path like this

```
gulp.src('/backroom/web/css/*.css')
```

it does not work.
But it works if I enter

```
gulp.src('../web/css/*.css')
```

You know why I cannot enter `gulp.src('/backroom/web/css/*.css')` ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gulp src is **relative** to your gulpfile.js so you need to go up one level and then down.  On the one that doesn't work, gulp is looking for a 'backroom' folder underneath the gulpfile.js.

Comment: Ok Mark thanks.

I thought there was a way to indicate the root path.